# Box2d Coordinate System

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d, coordinates

In the game I'm trying to code I got to have two bodies. One StaticBody and one DynamicBody. I want to have the DynamicBody on top of the StaticBody. Somehow all I get is this:

[image: Bug]

Is it possible that the viewports lower, left corner isn't at 0,0? And why can't the DynamicBody get on top of the StaticBody?

Comment: Box2D bodies are aligned from their center, not from lower left corner. It looks you set your smaller sodies position to 0,0 and its center is on 0,0

Answer (score -1):

a box2d rectangle has x and y coordinates with thw center in the center of rectangle... other this, to create a rectangle pay attention to give him halfWidth and halfHeight and not full.

for example, if you want a 2*2 rectangle in left down corner you have to build it with:

x = x+halfWidth
y = y+halfHeight
halfHeight =1
halfWidth =1